# Can not generate Android Apk from React Native Project on Windows

Tags: android, windows, exception, react-native, apk

I can't build android apk from react-native project on Windows machine. you can see on this screenshot the error message I am getting in cmd

[image]

Comment: try to build it with `--stacktrace` or `--info` option, atleast you will get idea  of an error, that in which library or module you are having issue.

Answer (score 0):

first of all AAPT is the Android Asset Packaging Tool .
There are some rules about how to name your assets. For example if I remember well you can't use upper case letter in the name. So change pictureNew.png to picturenew.png.

Then try to upgrade the sdk, I am using this right now :

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

and:

```
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
```

And check if you have included in your path the platform-tools from your android SDK, and the JAVA sdk path.